# Why is my VBA Code for Deleting a Row moving checkboxes in another row?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code that is meant to delete a particular row in ~200 excels in a folder. Every excel is formatted the same and contains a row that is either row 39 or row 40 with the words "DELETE ROW WHEN PRINT" in column A. It is unknown if it is row 39 or 40 for every excel. The code is meant to detect if row 39 or 40 has the text "DELETE ROW WHEN PRINT" in column A, delete the row for every excel in the folder, save the excels and close them. For some reason however, it is moving check boxes that start 2 rows below the row being deleted. Nothing else is being moved besides the text boxes. I dont understand why this is happening, does anyone have any suggestions? I posted pictures of before / after running the macro, and the code is below.

Thanks!

[After Running VBA Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iNGC.jpg)

[Before Running VBA Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzOE4.jpg)

Code:

```
Sub PPGDeleteRowBOLOGNATest()

'Below is used to make code run faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Dim strExtension As String

    
    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\steve.argen\Documents\PPG\GW Sampling March 2020\PPG Balogna NUMBER 2\Final excel sheets\"
    ChDir strPath
    strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
        
        
        'wkbSource.Sheets("LowFlow GW front").View = xlNormalView
        
        With wkbSource.Sheets("LowFlow GW front")
            ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
        
            If wkbSource.Worksheets("LowFlow GW front").Range("A" & 39).Value = "DELETE ROW WHEN PRINT" Then
                wkbSource.Worksheets("LowFlow GW front").Rows(39).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
            
            If wkbSource.Worksheets("LowFlow GW front").Range("A" & 40).Value = "DELETE ROW WHEN PRINT" Then
                wkbSource.Worksheets("LowFlow GW front").Rows(40).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
            
            Application.CutCopyMode = False 'If you ever need to copy a large amount of info, this will hide any warnings
            ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
        End With
        
        wkbSource.Close savechanges:=True
        
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: If you right click on the text box --> Format Control --> Properties is Don't move or size with cells checked?

Comment: I cant click on the check boxes. They have a circle with a line through them. I cant edit the check boxes at all and I dont know why...

Comment: I've never seen that before and can't seem to recreate it. If your controls are activeX then you may need to go to the developer tab and check Design Mode.

Comment: I would check that there are know merged cells in the row deleted. Merged rows in specific columns may make all the merge deletion to move things up or dowm. On the other hand, if the row is removed manually the same happens?